# How to specialize on a type projection in Scala?

Tags: scala, types

**Statement of the question**

Consider a type `T` that contains an abstract type member `A`:

```
trait T {
  type A
}
```

I'd like to create a class that takes a `T0 <: T` as a type parameter, but specializes on the *type projection* `T0#A`. For example, in the following, can the method `foo` be specialized?

```
class Foo[T0 <: T] {
  def foo(a: T0#A, f: T0#A => T0#A) = f(a)
}
```

Note that annotating `T0` with `@specialized` will not achieve the desired result. Is there is a good way to specialize `foo` on the type projection `T#A`?

**A limited solution: inherit from specialized parent class with extra parameter**

In this particular case, here's a way to specialize on `T0#A`:

```
trait SpecializedFoo[@specialized A0, T0 <: T] {
  def foo(a: A0, f: A0 => A0) = f(a)
}
class Foo2[T0 <: T] extends SpecializedFoo[T0#A, T0]
```

By inheriting from the specialized parent class `SpecializedFoo`, we ensure that `Foo2.foo` is specialized.

**Verification of specialization**

To verify that `Foo2.foo`, but not `Foo.foo`, is specialized, we can call them with an explicit `T` where `T#A` is a primitive Double,

```
trait ExplicitT extends T {
  type A = Double
}

object Test {
  def test1 = (new Foo[ExplicitT]).foo(1.0, _ + 1.0)
  def test2 = (new Foo2[ExplicitT]).foo(1.0, _ + 1.0)
}
```

The bytecode can be examined from the REPL with the command ":javap -v Test",

```
public double test1();
  Code:
   Stack=4, Locals=1, Args_size=1
   0:   new #16; //class Foo
   3:   dup
   4:   invokespecial   #18; //Method Foo."<init>":()V
   7:   dconst_1
   8:   invokestatic    #24; //Method scala/runtime/BoxesRunTime.boxToDouble:(D)Ljava/lang/Double;
   11:  new #26; //class Test$$anonfun$test1$1
   14:  dup
   15:  invokespecial   #27; //Method Test$$anonfun$test1$1."<init>":()V
   18:  invokevirtual   #31; //Method Foo.foo:(Ljava/lang/Object;Lscala/Function1;)Ljava/lang/Object;
   21:  invokestatic    #35; //Method scala/runtime/BoxesRunTime.unboxToDouble:(Ljava/lang/Object;)D
   24:  dreturn
  LineNumberTable: 
   line 13: 0


public double test2();
  Code:
   Stack=5, Locals=1, Args_size=1
   0:   new #38; //class Foo2
   3:   dup
   4:   invokespecial   #39; //Method Foo2."<init>":()V
   7:   dconst_1
   8:   new #41; //class Test$$anonfun$test2$1
   11:  dup
   12:  invokespecial   #42; //Method Test$$anonfun$test2$1."<init>":()V
   15:  invokeinterface #48,  4; //InterfaceMethod SpecializedFoo.foo$mcD$sp:(DLscala/Function1;)D
   20:  dreturn
  LineNumberTable: 
   line 14: 0
```

Note that boxing appears in `test1` but not `test2`.

**Limitations**

**Edit 7/9** The trick above is more limited than I realized at first. It won't work at all for specializing this case:

```
trait T {
  type A
  def x: A
  def f: A => Double
}

class Foo[T0 <: T] {
  def foo(t: T0) = t.f(t.x)
}
```

I see no reason why a (hypothetical) compiler couldn't specialize on `A` *in principle*; a usual, the specialized versions would only be usable when a specific `T#A` is known at compile time. The natural practical solution is to lift `A` into a type parameter of `T`, but I was wondering if I could avoid that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a compiler limitation; one *cannot* generally specialize on elements of a type parameter. However, the proposed trick is good enough for my purposes:

```
trait Types {
  type A
  type B
}

trait GenOps[@specialized A, @specialized B] {
  ...
}

trait Ops[T <: Types] extends GenOps[T#A, T#B]
```

This way the trait `Ops` gets specialized because it inherits the specialized implementations in trait `GenOps`. My motivation is that I want trait `Ops` to take a single type parameter `T`, rather than both `T#A` and `T#B` (this becomes necessary when `Ops` also takes a higher kinded type that expects `T` as a parameter).

Answer (score 1):

I can't see how that could possibly work. Specialization is done when compiling the class, and, at that time, `A` isn't known.

Comment: The idea is that I want specialized methods on an implementing `class Bar extends Foo[S]` where `S <: T` is explicitly known at compile time and `S#A` is a primitive. I know this can work because using the trick above (i.e., a `SpecializedFoo` parent class with an extra type parameter) I was able to eliminate the boxing, which I verified with ":javap -v" in the Scala REPL. The sample code in the question is of course a simplification... maybe I should put more details.

Comment: I updated the question to be more explicit about how boxing appears, and how it can be removed with specialization.