# Why do these type arguments not conform to a type refinement?

Tags: scala, types, specialization, type-projection

Why does this Scala code fail to typecheck?

```
trait T { type A }
trait GenFoo[A0, S <: T { type A = A0 }]
trait Foo[S <: T] extends GenFoo[S#A, S]
```

I don't understand why "type arguments [S#A,S] do not conform to trait GenFoo's type parameter bounds [A0,S <: T{type A = A0}]". Is there a work-around?

**Edit**: As has been pointed out, the conformance error stems from the failure to verify `S <: T{type A = S#A}`. Daniel Sobral pointed to `-explaintypes`, which tells us:

```
S <: T{type A = S#A}?
  S <: T?
  true
  S specializes type A?
    this.A = this.A?
      S = this.type?
      false
    false
  false
false
```

I'm not sure how to interpret this.

Note that we get an illegal cyclic reference if we try to define,

```
trait Foo[S <: T { type A = S#A } ] extends GenFoo[S#A, S]
```

although the type refinement here doesn't seem to add any new information. (See also [Why is this cyclic reference with a type projection illegal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6719827/why-is-this-cyclic-reference-with-a-type-projection-illegal))

My motivation is to create a trait `Foo[S <: T]` that specializes on `S#A`, as in: [How to specialize on a type projection in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6631155/how-to-specialize-on-a-type-projection-in-scala)  To get this to work, I'm trying to surface `S#A` as an explicit parameter `A0` in the implementation trait `GenFoo`, which can be specialized directly. I was hoping to apply the type refinement idea from Miles Sabin's answer to [Why is this cyclic reference with a type projection illegal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6719827/why-is-this-cyclic-reference-with-a-type-projection-illegal) but I run into this conformance error.

Comment: Have you tried -explaintypes?

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I updated the question to include the output from -explaintypes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be the answer:

> S specializes type A?

The question about *specialize* comes from here: `T { type A = A0 }`. This is the type `T` with `type A` *specialized* -- meaning, it is more restricted than the original `T`.

The answer to that question is no -- there's no constrains on `S` that it be specialized.

Comment: The surprise to me is that there's a difference between `S <: T` and `S <: T { type A = S#A }`. Although the latter is specialized, it seems that this specialization adds no additional constraint on `S`. (Maybe a hint is that the latter yields an illegal cyclic reference error if one tries to use it directly.) Perhaps I am misunderstanding the meaning of the types, but it seems that this a practical, rather than fundamental, limitation in the Scala type system?

Answer (score 1):

In order to conform to the type constraints, `S` would have to be a subtype of `T { type A = A0 }`, but it is only a subtype of `T`.

Comment: But in this case `A0 = S#A`, so I would expect `S <: T { type A = S#A }`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert on this topic, I just played around with your code and found out that the problem is not the `S#A` part, but the `S` part.

If you write the code like this:

```
trait T { type A }
trait GenFoo[A0, S <: T] // the { type A = A0 } part is not there anymore
trait Foo[S <: T] extends GenFoo[S#A, S]
```

then it compiles, because `S` in `Foo[S <: T]` conforms to the `S` in `GenFoo[A0, S <: T]`.

In your example the compiler knows that `S` is a subtype of `T` and therefore has the `type A` defined, but it does not come to the point, where it can verify that the `A` in `S` is the `S#A`.