# Scala fails to infer the right type arguments

Tags: generics, scala, generic-type-argument

**Background info:** I'm currently trying to set up a generic graph library that includes a few different search algorithms (I've started with Dijkstra's). I've set up a few traits to represent methods that would be found in certain types of graphs (e.g. weighted, directed):

```
trait GraphOps[V,E] { ... }
trait WeightedGraphOps[V,E] extends GraphOps[V,E] { ... }
trait DirectedGraphOps[V,E] extends GraphOps[V,E] { ... }
object GraphOps{
  def Dijkstra[V,E,G <: WeightedGraphOps[V,E] with DirectedGraphOps[V,E]](graph:G, start:V) = { ... }
}
```

Elsewhere, I have a class as the concrete implementation of the weighted, directed graph that I want to run Dijkstra's algorithm on:

```
class GraphMap[T](...)
extends scala.collection.mutable.Map[Position,T]
with WeightedGraphOps[Position,Edge] with DirectedGraphOps[Position,Edge] { ... }
```

But when I try to test it out:

```
val graph = new GraphMap[Int](...)
val (dist, prev) = GraphOps.Dijkstra(graph, Position(0,0))
```

**Question:** I get the following error during compilation: `error: inferred type arguments [com.dylan.data.Position,Nothing,com.dylan.data.GraphMap[Int]] do not conform to method Dijkstra's type parameter bounds [V,E,G <: com.dylan.data.WeightedGraphOps[V,E] with com.dylan.data.DirectedGraphOps[V,E]]`
It took me long enough to notice that it's inferring my Edge  (`E`) type as `Nothing`, but I don't see why it's failing to successfully infer that it's supposed to be `Edge`. Why is it failing to infer that type parameter, and how can I fix it?

P.S. I tried doing the following, and got it to work, but this seems horribly inconvenient for what was supposed to be a convenience method:

```
type Helpful = WeightedGraphOps[Position,Edge] with DirectedGraphOps[Position,Edge]
val (dist, prev) = GraphOps.Dijkstra[Position,Edge,Helpful](graph, Position(0,0))
```

Comment: You do realize there's a graph library already, don't you?

Comment: Since I'm doing this for hobby, and since a few minutes of searching around didn't lead to a definitive answer, I figured I might as well put my own together.

Comment: I'm curious what term did you exactly google? I tried 'scala graph library' and got this: http://code.google.com/p/scala-graphs/ doesn't it this for you?

Comment: That project has no downloads and no source code. I searched for that exact term and did find that, along with the StackOverflow question mentioning that it was dead.

Comment: The graph library linked below is being actively developed with hopes to be included in the Scala collections library. The release notes and roadmap looks promising. http://www.assembla.com/spaces/scala-graph/wiki

Comment: Thanks for the link- I'll keep that on my radar

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Daniel is probably right that the existing Scala type inferencer needs more direct information to figure out the that `E` must be `Edge`. Also, it is my understanding that type inference is intentionally under-specified to make way for future improvements.

Anyway, I think you can take another approach to your design that will resolve the type inference problem: use type *members* rather than parameters. I've illustrated what I mean with self-contained code below. The key idea is that types `E` and `V` become part of the `GraphOps` type, but they can still be surfaced as type parameters by using a *type refinement*, as in the `Dijkstra` method.

```
trait GraphOps { type E; type V }
trait WeightedGraphOps extends GraphOps { }
trait DirectedGraphOps extends GraphOps { }
object GraphOps{
  def Dijkstra[V0, G <: (WeightedGraphOps{type V = V0})
                         with (DirectedGraphOps{type V = V0})]
      (graph:G, start:V0) = { }
}

case class Position(x: Int, y: Int)
case class Edge()

case class GraphMap[T]() extends WeightedGraphOps with DirectedGraphOps {
  type E = Edge
  type V = Position
}

object Test {
  val graph = new GraphMap[Int]( )
  GraphOps.Dijkstra(graph, Position(0,0))
}
```

**Edit**:  <del>One potential limitation of this type member approach is that puts less constraints on the type parameter `G` in method `Dijkstra`. Specifically, the bounds `WeightedGraphOps` and `DirectedGraphOps` aren't constrained to have the same type members `E`. I'm not sure how to resolve this without bumping into the type inference problem you originally reported. One approach would be the pattern in this question: [Why do these type arguments not conform to a type refinement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6795623/why-do-these-type-arguments-not-conform-to-a-type-refinement) , but it seems the Scala compiler can't handle it.</del>

**Edit2** Ignore the above paragraph. As Dylan mentioned in the comments, for this [diamond inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_problem) situation, Scala nicely ensures the consistency of the type `E`. For example, the following compiles fine:

```
trait GraphOps { type E; type V }
trait WeightedGraphOps extends GraphOps { def f(e: E) }
trait DirectedGraphOps extends GraphOps { def e: E }
object GraphOps{
  def Dijkstra[V0, G <: (WeightedGraphOps{type V = V0}) with (DirectedGraphOps{type V = V0})] (graph:G, start:V0) = {
    graph.f(graph.e)
  }
}
```

Comment: This helped me out, thanks! I'm not sure whether I should be worried about the lack of edge type constraint- I'm probably missing something, but I'm failing to create an object that mixes in both Ops types but with different `E` types. Is it even possible?

Comment: Interesting. It sounds like the diamond problem ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_problem ) for types. For values, Scala's resolution to the diamond problem is that one value overrides the other, based on a linearization scheme. For types, I'm not surprised this is disallowed to avoid inconsistencies.

Answer (score 2):

Why is it supposed to be `Edge`? If you look at the declaration of `Dijkstra`, you'll see that none of the parameters make reference to `E`: `(graph:G, start:V)`. So Scala has a clue what `G` is supposed to be, and what `V` is supposed to be. There's no parameter making reference to `E`.

Comment: But couldn't a sufficiently clever Scala compiler figure it out at this call site? Knowing that `graph` has type `WeightedGraphOps[Position, Edge] with ...` basically fixes what `E` has to be to make the types work.

Comment: It's supposed to be `Edge` because that's the type of the edges in the GraphMap. The implementation of Dijkstra's needs the type so I can't just leave it out.

Comment: @Dylan I understand that you have a problem, I'm just trying to get you to understand type inference constrains better, so you'll write code more easily. The problem here is this: types are inferred from parameters. `G` is inferred from `graph`. What is the parameter `E` is supposed to be inferred from? It won't be inferred from the type constraints -- that is just what it is checked against, to what it is inferred from.

Comment: I see, so let's say my method signature was `(graph:G, start:V, edgesToExclude:E*)`; so long as I call the method with some list of Edges, the inference should succeed, but if I called it with no edges excluded, I would still have the same problem as before, correct?

Comment: @Dylan See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6888136/type-infered-to-nothing-in-scala) for a way around the problem -- basically, parameterizing `G` so that `E` and `V` can be attached to the parameter.