# What are type projections useful for?

Tags: scala, type-systems

What are type projections in Scala useful for? Why does Scala's type system support both type projections and path dependent types? What was the rationale behind this design decision?

Answer (score 13):

Not a complete answer, but here are some uses for type projections that I have encountered:

- *Type level metaprogramming*. For examples, see Michid's series (parts [I](http://michid.wordpress.com/2008/10/29/meta-programming-with-scala-conditional-compilation-and-loop-unrolling/), [II](http://michid.wordpress.com/2008/07/30/meta-programming-with-scala-part-ii-multiplication/), [III](http://michid.wordpress.com/2008/08/27/meta-programming-with-scala-part-iii-partial-function-application/)), Jesper's [implementation of HList](http://jnordenberg.blogspot.com/2008/08/hlist-in-scala.html), and the [series at Apocalisp](http://apocalisp.wordpress.com/2010/06/08/type-level-programming-in-scala/).
- A workaround to enable type inference (for examples, here are some previous SO questions [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6892781/why-doesnt-scala-fully-infer-type-parameters-when-type-parameters-are-nested/6893057#6893057), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6881393/scala-fails-to-infer-the-right-type-arguments), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6888136/type-infered-to-nothing-in-scala)).
- A way to bundle a bunch of types into a single type parameter. For example, in a matrix library I'm developing, I define `trait Scalar { type A; type B; type C; ... }` and then pass it as a single parameter to my matrix trait, `trait Matrix[S <: Scalar] ...` The individual types can be referred to as `S#A`, `S#B`, and so on. Between two matrices of type `Matrix[S]`, for the same `S`, these types will be compatible (unlike what would be the case with path dependent types).

Comment: Jesper's post you link states that the code doesn't work, but later post explain that Scala's newer version supports it:
http://jnordenberg.blogspot.com/2009/09/type-lists-and-heterogeneously-typed.html

Answer (score 9):

One thing type projections can be used for is partial type application:

```
({type λ[x]=Tuple2[Int,x]})#λ
```