# Is it possible to define a function return type based on a defined mapping from the type of a function argument?

Tags: scala, types, implicit, implicit-typing

Ideally I'd like to be able to do the following in Scala:

```
import Builders._

val myBuilder = builder[TypeToBuild] // Returns instance of TypeToBuildBuilder
val obj = myBuilder.methodOnTypeToBuildBuilder(...).build()
```

In principle the goal is simply to be able to 'map' `TypeToBuild` to `TypeToBuildBuilder` using *external* mapping definitions (i.e. assume no ability to change these classes) and leverage this in type inferencing.

I got the following working with `AnyRef` types:

```
import Builders._

val myBuilder = builder(TypeToBuild)
myBuilder.methodOnTypeToBuildBuilder(...).build()

object Builders {
    implicit val typeToBuildBuilderFactory =
        new BuilderFactory[TypeToBuild.type, TypeToBuildBuilder]
    def builder[T, B](typ: T)(implicit ev: BuilderFactory[T, B]): B = ev.create
}

class BuilderFactory[T, B: ClassTag] {
    def create: B = classTag[B].runtimeClass.newInstance().asInstanceOf[B]
}
```

Note that the type is passed as a function argument rather than a type argument.

I'd be supremely happy just to find out how to get the above working with `Any` types, rather than just `AnyRef` types.  It seems this limitation comes since Singleton types are only supported for `AnyRef`s (i.e. my use of TypeToBuild.type).

That being said, an answer that solves the original 'ideal' scenario (using a type argument instead of a function argument) would be fantastic!

**EDIT**

A possible solution that requires `classOf[_]` (would really love not needing to use `classOf`!):

```
import Builders._

val myBuilder = builder(classOf[TypeToBuild])
myBuilder.methodOnTypeToBuildBuilder(...).build()

object Builders {
    implicit val typeToBuildBuilderFactory =
        new BuilderFactory[classOf[TypeToBuild], TypeToBuildBuilder]
    def builder[T, B](typ: T)(implicit ev: BuilderFactory[T, B]): B = ev.create
}

class BuilderFactory[T, B: ClassTag] {
    def create: B = classTag[B].runtimeClass.newInstance().asInstanceOf[B]
}
```

Being able to just use `builder(TypeToBuild)` is really just a win in elegance/brevity.  Being able to use `builder[TypeToBuild]` would be cool as perhaps this could one day work (with type inference advancements in Scala):

```
val obj: TypeToBuild = builder.methodOnTypeToBuildBuilder(...).build();
```

Here is a complete, working example using `classOf`: http://ideone.com/94rat3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll resort to answering my own question since a Redditor ended up giving me the answer I was looking for and they appear to have chosen not to respond here.

```
trait Buildable[T] {
  type Result
  def newBuilder: Result
}

object Buildable {
  implicit object ABuildable extends Buildable[A] {
    type Result = ABuilder
    override def newBuilder = new ABuilder
  }
  implicit object BBuildable extends Buildable[B] {
    type Result = BBuilder
    override def newBuilder = new BBuilder
  }
}

def builder[T](implicit B: Buildable[T]): B.Result = B.newBuilder

class ABuilder {
  def method1() = println("Call from ABuilder")
}

class BBuilder {
  def method2() = println("Call from BBuilder")
}
```

Then you will get:

```
scala> builder[A].method1()
Call from ABuilder

scala> builder[B].method2()
Call from BBuilder
```

You can see the reddit post here: http://www.reddit.com/r/scala/comments/2542x8/is_it_possible_to_define_a_function_return_type/

And a full working version here: http://ideone.com/oPI7Az

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Scala supports return types based on the parameters types. An example of this would be methods in the collections API like `map` that use the `CanBuildFrom` typeclass to return the desired type.

I'm not sure what you are trying to do with your example code, but maybe you want something like:

```
trait Builder[-A, +B] {
    def create(x: A): B
}

object Builders {
    implicit val int2StringBuilder = new Builder[Int, String] {
      def create(x: Int) = "a" * x
    }
    def buildFrom[A, B](x: A)(implicit ev: Builder[A, B]): B = ev.create(x)
}

import Builders._

buildFrom(5)
```

The magic with `newInstance` only works for concrete classes that have a constructor that takes no parameters, so it probably isn't generic enough to be useful.

Comment: Thanks for your input!  The solution you've given has a fixed `Builder[B]` return type so I can only use methods general to all `Builder[_]` on the return value.  Also it would require modifying the objects I am trying to work with (I specified 'assume no ability to change these classes').  I understand and am happy with the `newInstance` restriction.
What I am trying to do is return a completely different class based on the given type parameter, and then directly call methods exclusive to that returned type.  Thank you for telling me about `CanBuildFrom` - I will investigate.

Comment: Okay, so the `CanBuildFrom` technique is basically similar to what I'm doing in my solution.  It, however, is used in a situation where it can infer types based on the instance the method is called on and the given argument.  I am simply trying to lookup builders based on the object they build, so unless I pass classOf[ObjectToBuild] as an argument, I don't have this.  That is in fact a possible solution to my whole question - but it would be great to find a way just using the type, without classOf.

Comment: The `CanBuildFrom` pattern allows types to be inferred from the return type as well. For example, read up on `scala.collection.breakOut`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1715681/scala-2-8-breakout. Basically, `list.map(x => x)(collection.breakOut)` will return a different type based on context.

Comment: Indeed it does support inferring based on the expected return type, as does Scala in general.  I am looking to specify the return type based on a given type parameter to the method combined with some definition mapping that type to another type.  So that if I somehow define that ClassA maps to ClassB, then *if* I specify myMethod[ClassA] its return type is ClassB.  And in general, given known mapping X -> Y, myMethod[X] has return type Y.

Comment: Do you mean an `X` which doesn't appear in either the parameters or return type? There isn't any sensible reason to do that. You either want to pass `Y` as the type parameter, or pass the builder instance around explicitly.

Comment: As I originally specified, being able to say builder(X) would be cool as well.  My ideal scenario is builder[X], which as I've also specified, I *do* think is useful.  I do not want to pass Y as the type parameter, nor do I want to pass a builder instance around explicitly.  If I did that, code would need to know directly the names of all builder types.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not afraid of implicit conversions, you could do something like this:

```
import scala.language.implicitConversions

trait BuilderMapping[TypeToBuild, BuilderType] {
    def create: BuilderType
}

case class BuilderSpec[TypeToBuild]()

def builder[TypeToBuild] = BuilderSpec[TypeToBuild]

implicit def builderSpecToBuilder[TypeToBuild, BuilderType]
    (spec: BuilderSpec[TypeToBuild])
    (implicit ev: BuilderMapping[TypeToBuild, BuilderType]) = ev.create




case class Foo(count: Int)

case class FooBuilder() {
    def translate(f: Foo) = "a" * f.count
}

implicit val FooToFooBuilder = new BuilderMapping[Foo, FooBuilder] {
  def create = FooBuilder()
}

val b = builder[Foo]
println(b.translate(Foo(3)))
```

The implicit conversions aren't too bad, since they're constrained to these builder-oriented types. The conversion is needed to make `b.translate` valid.

It looked like wingedsubmariner's answer was most of what you wanted, but you didn't want to specify both `TypeToBuild` and `BuilderType` (and you didn't necessarily want to pass a value). To achieve that, we needed to break up that single generic signature into two parts, which is why the BuilderSpec type exists.

It might also be possible to use something like partial generic application (see the answers to [a question that I asked earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7643493/in-scala-is-there-a-shorthand-for-reducing-a-generic-types-arity)), though I can't put the pieces together in my head at the moment.